# Lambda raise a syntax error on a match operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a Lambda function that works on my machine, but when I test it I receive the following error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 64)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "requestId": "ae5f2481-a836-4b4e-8c8d-a82ccd12c630",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 64\n        match operation:\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: ae5f2481-a836-4b4e-8c8d-a82ccd12c630 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 64
        match operation:END RequestId: ae5f2481-a836-4b4e-8c8d-a82ccd12c630
REPORT RequestId: ae5f2481-a836-4b4e-8c8d-a82ccd12c630  Duration: 1.34 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 35 MB  Init Duration: 117.69 ms

Request ID
ae5f2481-a836-4b4e-8c8d-a82ccd12c630
```

So after hours wasted:

- I cannot see any syntax error.
- I've tried bundling the enum package (don't know if it is necessary).
- I've also commented any line that uses external parameters.
- I'm using Python 3.9 in Lambda and python 3.10 in local.
- The the logs point always to line 64     `match operation:` in the function `get_url`

This is the code until the function with the error:

```
import requests
import json
from enum import Enum
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import base64

max_number_of_digit = 1
base_url = "https://somesite.io"
app_version = "version-test/"
bubble_api_token = "some api token"
pdf_creator_api_token = 'some other api token'


class APP_ENTITY(str, Enum):
    PROJECT = "project"
    COMPANY = "company"
    PAYMENT = "payment"
    TRANCHE = "tranche"
    COST_ITEMS = "payment"
    DOCUMENT = "document"


class OPERATIONS(int, Enum):
    CREATE = 1
    DELETE = 2
    PATCH = 3
    READ = 4
    GET = 5


document = dict()
customer = dict()
base_assets = [
    'bank.png',
    'calculator.png',
    'card.png',
    'caret.png',
    'jetbrains-mono-v11-latin-500.woff2',
    'jetbrains-mono-v11-latin-regular.woff2',
    'line.png',
    'logo.svg',
    'poppins-v19-latin-300.woff2',
    'poppins-v19-latin-500.woff2',
    'poppins-v19-latin-600.woff2',
    'poppins-v19-latin-regular.woff2',
    'style.css'
]


def set_app_version(event):
    global app_version
    result = "version-test/"
    try:
        result = event['queryStringParameters']['appversion']
        result = "" if (result.lower() != 'test') else "version-test/"
    except:
        result = "version-test/"
    app_version = result
    return result


def get_url(operation: OPERATIONS, entity: APP_ENTITY, cursor: int = 0, record_id: str = "", project_id: str = ""):
    match operation:
        case OPERATIONS.CREATE:
            result = base_url + \
                "/{}api/1.1/obj/{}/bulk".format(app_version, entity)
        case OPERATIONS.DELETE:
            result = base_url + \
                "/{}api/1.1/obj/{}/".format(app_version, entity)
        case OPERATIONS.PATCH:
            result = base_url + \
                "/{}api/1.1/obj/{}/{}".format(app_version, entity, record_id)
        case OPERATIONS.READ:
            match entity:
                case APP_ENTITY.COST_ITEMS:
                    result = base_url + \
                        "/{}api/1.1/obj/{}/?api_token={}&cursor={}&constraints=".format(
                            app_version, entity, bubble_api_token, cursor)
                    constraints = [
                        {
                            "key": "type",
                            "constraint_type": "equals",
                            "value": "development"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "project",
                            "constraint_type": "equals",
                            "value": project_id
                        }]
                    constraints = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
                        json.dumps(constraints))
                    result = result+constraints
        case OPERATIONS.GET:
            result = base_url + \
                "/{}api/1.1/obj/{}/{}".format(app_version, entity, record_id)
    return result
```

Below a screenshot of the lambda console.
[Lambda console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5sv8.png)

And here a screenshot of the error:
[Lambda error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl8Ij.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` and `case` are new additions in Python 3.10. **Lambda does not support Python 3.10,** thus you are getting the error. You have to port back your code to work with Python 3.9